# Drawing a line on Google Maps with D3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, d3.js, svg

I am trying to modify the code asked in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13098244/draw-paths-using-d3-in-google-maps-overlay) based on the demo on integrating D3 with google maps.

Essentially, all I want is to draw a line on the map between given 2 points. The line also be updated with respect to the changes in the map.

So far, with the code above - I am able to see the svg element being there but can't see the line. Also, I think I might be missing a conversion to pixels.

```
<svg width="100%" style="position: absolute;"><path d="M8067.524444444445,48446.32912634293L8022.013333333334,48446.32912634293" stroke="red" class="line aaa"></path></svg>
```

And, here is the code:

```
<html>
```

```
    html, body, #map {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    .stations {
      position: absolute;
    }

    .stations, .stations svg.aaa {
      position: absolute;
    }

    .stations border {
      position: absolute;
     stroke: black;
     stroke-width: 2px;
    }

    .stations svg.aaa {
      width: 60px;
      height: 20px;
      padding-right: 100px;
      font: 10px sans-serif;
    }

    .stations circle {
      fill: brown;
      stroke: black;
      stroke-width: 1.5px;
    }

        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="map"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">

    // create map
    var map = new google.maps.Map(d3.select("#map").node(), {
      zoom: 6,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.76487, -122.41948),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    });


    var data = [
        { name: 'pt1', lng: -122.28, lat: 38.2 },
        { name: 'pt2', lng: -122.05, lat: 38.0 },
        { name: 'pt3', lng: -122.12, lat: 37.67 },
        { name: 'pt4', lng: -121.82, lat: 37.7 },
        { name: 'pt5', lng: -121.95, lat: 38.38 },
        { name: 'pt6', lng: -121.78, lat: 36.93 },
        { name: 'pt7', lng: -122.25, lat: 37.52 },
        { name: 'pt8', lng: -122.82, lat: 38.5 },
        { name: 'pt9', lng: -121.92, lat: 37.37 },
        { name: 'pt10', lng: -122.37, lat: 37.62 },
        { name: 'pt11', lng: -121.23, lat: 37.9 },
    ];

    var line = [[[-122.28, 38.2], [-121.28, 37.2]]]

    // Load the station data. When the data comes back, create an overlay.
    var overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();

    // Add the container when the overlay is added to the map.
    overlay.onAdd = function() {
      var layer = d3.select(this.getPanes().overlayLayer).append("div")
            .attr("height", "100%")
            .attr("width", "100%")
            .attr("class", "stations")
            .attr("id", "layer");

      layer[0][0].style.width = "1366px";
      layer[0][0].parentNode.style.width = "100%";
      layer[0][0].parentNode.style.height = "100%";
      layer[0][0].parentNode.parentNode.style.width = "100%";
      layer[0][0].parentNode.parentNode.style.height = "100%";
      layer[0][0].parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.width = "100%";
      layer[0][0].parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.height = "100%";
      layer[0][0].parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.width = "100%";
      layer[0][0].parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.height = "100%";

      // Draw each marker as a separate SVG element.
      // We could use a single SVG, but what size would it have?
      overlay.draw = function() {
        var projection = this.getProjection(),
            padding = 10;

        var marker = layer.selectAll("svg")
            .data( data )
            .each(transform) // update existing markers
          .enter().append("svg:svg")
            .each(transform)
            .attr("class", "marker aaa")

        marker.append("svg:circle")
            .attr("r", 4.5)
            .attr("cx", padding )
            .attr("cy", padding );

        // add a label.
        marker.append("svg:text")
            .attr("x", padding + 7)
            .attr("y", padding)
            .attr("dy", ".31em")
            .text( function(d) {
              return d.name; }
            );




        var v = d3.geom.voronoi( translate(data) );
        console.log( "v is :" );
        console.log( v );


          var lineEdges = layer.selectAll("path")
                  .data(line)
                  .attr("d",translate_edge)
          .enter()
          .append("svg:svg").attr("width", "100%").attr("width","100%").style("position", "absolute")
          .append("svg:path")
            .attr("d",translate_edge)
                  .attr("stroke", "red")
          .attr("class", "line aaa")

          function translate_edge(d)
          {
              var c1 = _projection( d[0][0], d[0][1] )
              var c2 = _projection( d[1][0], d[1][1] )
              console.log( 'PATH: ' + c1)
              console.log( 'M'+ c1[0] +','+ c1[1]+ 'L' + c2[0] +','+ c2[1])
                var p = 'M'+ c1[0] +','+ c1[1]+ 'L' + c2[0] +','+ c2[1]

              return p;

          }

        function translate(data) {
          var d = []
          for( var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
            var c = [ data[i].lat, data[i].lng ]
            d.push( c )
          }
          return d
        }

        function _projection( lat, lng ) {
          e = new google.maps.LatLng( lat, lng );
          e = projection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(e);
          return [ e.x - padding, e.y - padding]
          // return [ e.x, e.y ]
        }

        function transform(d) {
          e = _projection( d.lat, d.lng )
          console.log("marker " + d.lat +', ' + d.lng + " -> left: " + e[0] +", top: " + e[1] )
          return d3.select(this)
              .style("left", e[0] + "px")
              .style("top", e[1] + "px");
        }

        function transform_path(data) {
          var d = []
          console.log(data)
          for( var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
            var c = _projection( data[i][0], data[i][1] )
            console.log( ' path point: ' + JSON.stringify(data[i]) + ' -> left: ' + c[0] + ", top: " + c[1])
            d.push( c )
          }
          // console.log(d)
          return d
        }

      };
    };

    // Bind our overlay to the map…
    overlay.setMap(map);

</script>
```

Any idea is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I feel like I just answered this [question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35703407/how-do-i-create-lines-between-svg-elements-in-d3)

Comment: Thank you very much @Mark, exactly what I needed!

Comment: Cool, going to close this as duplicate then.